# string function

Tags: matrices

Jane loves string more than anything.

She made a function related to the string some days ago and forgot about it.

She is now confused about calculating the value of this function.

She has a string $T$ with her, and value of string $S$ over function $f $can be calculated as given below:

$f(S)=|S|\times$ Number of times $S$ occurring in $T$.

Jane wants to know the maximum value of $f(S)$ among all the substrings $(S)$ of string $T$.

Can you help her?

---

Input Format: A single line containing string $T$ in small letter ('a' - 'z').

Output Format: An integer containing the value of output.

Constraints: $1 \leq |T| \leq 105$.

---

Sample Input #$00$: aaaaaa

Sample Output #$00$: $12$

Explanation #$00$:

- $f('a') = 6$
- $f('aa') = 10$
- $f('aaa') = 12$
- $f('aaaa') = 12$
- $f('aaaaa') = 10$
- $f('aaaaaa') = 6$

---

Sample Input #$01$: abcabcddd

Sample Output #$01$: $9$

Explanation #$01$:

- $f('a') = 2$
- $f('b') = 2$
- $f('c') = 2$
- $f('ab') = 4$
- $f('bc') = 4$
- $f('ddd') = 3$
- $f('abc') = 6$
- $f('abcabcddd') = 9$

---

Among the function values $9$ is the maximum one.

Comment: Please include some context in the question, such as your thought on it, and what is it for. Also, this is probably the wrong site to ask, but then again this can be considered mathematical enough here.

Comment: I have seen a nice approach, usefull in this problem. It was probably in Jon Bentley's 'Programming pearls', something about finding the longest repeating substring in a book.

Comment: @Gina This is a programming question i need to solve it, I'm beginner in programming, i'm troubling in this problem, I thought first form the sub-strings of the given sequence single character to full-length string and count the pattern match in the given string and maximum amongs all, but it is much slow process as i think.

Comment: @CiaPan, Thanx for replying, as i have scanned e-copy of this book, so i'm unable to search but i see in index and not found there can you tell me the page number if it possible to you, otherwise reading full book takes time.

Answer (score 0):

The longest repeating substring isn't necessarily the one that gives the maximum value. For example:

**lrs("aaaaaa")** gives **aaaaa**, which in turn leads to an overall result value of **10** (lenght = 5 * number of occurrences = 2), but the expected max value is actually **12**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I mixed two books and it was in Sedgewick's 'Algorithms in C++'...
Anyway the trick was to prepare an array of all string suffixes, that is an array of pointers pointing to every position in the string. The array was sorted and then each pair of adjacent positions were checked for the common prefix. (That's easy in C/C++ which identify 'a pointer to the character' with 'a string beginning with that character'.)

It's not enough to see the common prefix of suffixes in your problem, however you can easily see all instances of every repeating substring you find.

Assume input 'bababba'. Then array of suffixes is:
('bababba', 'ababba', 'babba', 'abba', 'bba', 'ba', 'a')
and sorted:
('a', 'ababba', 'abba', 'ba', 'bababba', 'babba', 'bba')

Items 'a' and 'ababba' have a single-char prefix in common, and that prefix appears also in 'abba' – and nowhere else. So it scores $1\times 3=3$.
Next pair have common prefix 'ab', so we test

- 'a', which doesn't appear in further positions, so it scores $1\times 2=2$ (and gets discarded due to a previous result of $3$) and
- 'ab', which also appears only in those two positions and scores $2\times 2=4$.

Then 'abba' and 'ba' have no common prefix, next 'ba' and 'bababba' have 'b' and 'ba', which score $1\times 4 = 4$ and $2\times 3=6$, respectively.
Next 'bababba' and 'babba' have prefixes 'b', 'ba' and 'bab', two of which get discarded and 'bab' scores $3\times 2=6$.
Finally 'babba' and 'bba' have only 'b' prefix with score $1$.

Winner repeating substrings are 'ba' and 'bab', both with a score of 6.

Apart from all repeating substrings you need to consider non-repeating substrings, the longest of which is of course the whole input string. In this example 'bababba' scores $7\times 1=7$, and this becomes the answer.

Comment: Thanx @Ciapan Such a nice example